# Flask, cannot assign requested address

Tags: python, sockets, flask

I'm trying to run a flask app on a remote server, so I can access it from other computers. The server has a public IP and I configured the flask to run on that IP. But when I run the script I get the following traceback

Note: I've removed the public IP from the traceback and my code.

```
 * Running on **public ip** 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testServer.py", line 14, in <module>
    app.run(host='62.60.19.189',port=5000)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 772, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 710, in run_simple
    inner()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 692, in inner
    passthrough_errors, ssl_context).serve_forever()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 486, in make_server
    passthrough_errors, ssl_context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 410, in __init__
    HTTPServer.__init__(self, (host, int(port)), handler)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 402, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 108, in server_bind
    SocketServer.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 413, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
  File "<string>", line 1, in bind
socket.error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

Here is my code

```
import flask

app = flask.Flask("My app")

@app.route('/myroute', methods=['POST'])
def foobar():
        print flask.request.form
        return '<br>'.join('{0}: {1}'.format(*pair) for pair in flask.request.form.items())




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='public IP',port=5000)
```

Comment: Is that server *directly* configured to run on that IP address, or are you running behind a router and *it* has the IP address (e.g. your server has a private IP address and the router uses NAT - network address translation)?

Comment: This is *not* a problem unique to Flask, by the way.

Comment: No, I connect to the server using a different IP after I'm connected to a VPN, I'm running the python code in the remote server and was given a public IP to run flask on it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can only directly bind to an IP address that the server has been configured for; behind a router running Network Address Translation (NAT) your internal IP address will be different.

Either bind directly to that internal IP address, or use `'0.0.0.0'` to listen on all interfaces. You may still need to configure the router to forward a specific port to your internal server.

Comment: Tried using `0.0.0.0` but that seems to return `Address already in use` error

Comment: @cyberbemon: which would mean there is already something bound to that port. See [Finding the process that is using a certain port in Linux](http://superuser.com/q/42843) to figure out what is bound to the port.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get it running on '0.0.0.0'

Comment: @Cleb: So `192.x.y.z` is not a valid IP address **on your computer**. Something else maps that IP address to your computer, *or* you got your IP address wrong somehow.

Comment: @Cleb: No, that doesn't mean it is correct. Network address translation (NAT) on a router can rewrite your IP addresses. You need to look at your computer configuration directly. It depends on your OS how you do that.

Answer (score 2):

The IP you want to bind a socket to must be directly available on an interface of the machine. This seems not be the case here.

- If you're behind a NAT: use port-forwarding
- If you're using a VPN and the VPN adapter of the server is not always up, try using "0.0.0.0" as an address. Beware: It will listen on *all* interfaces available. Create firewall rules to block access via interfaces you don't want to listen to when using this.