# socket.error:[errno 99] cannot assign requested address : flask and python

Tags: python, sockets, docker, flask, nat

I am having the same problem like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26280868/flask-cannot-assign-requested-address?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246103/socket-errorerrno-99-cannot-assign-requested-address-and-namespace-in-python)

I am Trying to run a flask app inside docker container.It works fine with '0.0.0.0' but it throws error with my ip address

I am behind a corporate proxy. When i checked my ip address with ipconfig, it showed IP Address as : `10.***.**.**` And I am using docker toolbox where my container ip is 172.17.0.2 and VM IP Address is 192.168.99.100.

I have a flask app running inside this docker with host

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host= '0.0.0.0')
```

works fine. But when i change it to my ip address

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(host= '10.***.**')
```

throws error :

> socket.error:[errno 99] cannot assign requested address

I checked again the ip address with a simple flask application which is running on local (i.e without docker)

```
 if __name__ == "__main__":
            app.run(host= '10.***.**')
```

It worked fine.

So the problem is coming only when running inside the docker. And that's because i am behind a router running NAT with internal ip address. And how do i find this internal ip address with NAT? I have already done port forwarding for flask application with port 5000.

```
> iptables -t nat -A DOCKER -p tcp --dport 5000 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:5000
> iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE -p tcp --source 172.17.0.2 --destination 172.17.0.2 --dport https
> iptables -A DOCKER -j ACCEPT -p tcp --destination 172.17.0.2 --dport https
```

Comment: Looks like such action is incompatible with docker container network driver (https://docs.docker.com/network/#network-drivers). Try to change it. And secondly, why do you need to specify some IP address instead of 0.0.0.0 that means "listen all interfaces" ? So you can use 0.0.0.0 if you need to gain access to your app on the LAN, and use 127.0.0.1 to gain access to your service from localhost only.

Comment: I want other computers to connect to this api . Is there a way i can do this with '0.0.0.0' or with ''127.0.0.1?

Comment: Yes, to let other computers on the LAN connect to your service just use `0.0.0.0` address in app.run() function and expose desired port from your docker container to your host PC. To expose port you need to 1) specify `EXPOSE` directive in Dockerfile and 2) run container with `-p <port_on_host>:<port_in_container>`. Here you can find simple example: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose
Let me know if I can post this comment as an answer for your question.

Comment: I got it. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To let other computers on the LAN connect to your service just use `0.0.0.0` address in `app.run()` function and expose desired port from your docker container to your host PC.

To expose port you need to

1) specify `EXPOSE` directive in Dockerfile

2) run container with `-p <port_on_host>:<port_in_container>` parameter.

For example:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:17.10

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apache2

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl"]
CMD ["-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

Build:

```
docker build -t image_name .
```

Run:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 image_name
```

Check:

```
curl http://localhost
```

P.S. make sure that 80 port is not used by another app on your host PC before running container. If this port is already in use - specify another port, for example `8080`:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80 image_name
```

And then check:

```
curl http://localhost:8080
```

Docs are [here](http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose).

Answer (score 0):

The answer of  [OSError [Errno 99] - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23843165/oserror-errno-99-python) applies here also.

If it works using the ip address but not using hostname.

Removing double localhost in `/etc/hosts` should be solution. hosts file should look something like this (mapping   ip  to  hostname)

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   your_hostname_here

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Answer by  @'Artsiom Praneuski' is only concerned with Docker configuration, which is all relevant in docker container setup but does not point to Python environment fix(both container and normal setup).